# Routing flow when addressing the router by public IP in it's local network

Tags: networking, router, dns, ip, nat

I am running a RPi Server in my local network. In my router I have exposed the ports 443 and 80 for this server as it's running ownCloud and I want to access it from everywhere.
I'd like to know how the routing is working in the case that I am addressing the server by it's domain which is linked to the public router IP, although I currently am in the **local network**.

AFAIK the router has it's own local DNS-table. So is it correct that, when I am looking up the domain, it most of the time automatically "knows" the corresponding IP (which is the public IP of the router itself)?
Also, if the router sees the IP, does it know that the IP belongs to itself?
So if I am addressing my domain, there is **no network traffic** going out of my local network?

Answer (score 1):

> AFAIK the router has it's own local DNS-table. So is it correct that, when I am looking up the domain, it most of the time automatically "knows" the corresponding IP (which is the public IP of the router itself)?

No. The router might have its own DNS table *for local domains* (e.g. `*.home`), but it does not care about external domains. When you're accessing a public domain such as `owncloud.example.com`, the router has no idea where the domain points until it actually does a lookup first.

> Also, if the router sees the IP, does it know that the IP belongs to itself? So if I am addressing my domain, there is no network traffic going out of my local network?

Yes. All addresses, even those assigned to different interfaces, are considered to be local – the router will never forward traffic that was sent to its own address.

But note that while you can access the *router itself* through its WAN IP address, you usually cannot use *port forwarding* rules when doing so – at least not as long as the client and server are from the same subnet. (This is because replies from your server  will go straight to the client, so the router won't get a chance to "undo" the address translation.) So don't be surprised if you just see the router's own login page.

Some routers can work around this using an option called "NAT loopback" or "NAT hairpinning", which rewrites the source address in addition to the destination. You might want to enable this.